# Xamarin Android Linker Error when Linking is On, and Unspecific error when Linking is Off

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my visual Studio i have reached a point for my Xamarin Forms project, where i cannot build it, neither in debug or release mode.

In release mode, Linking on my Android project is set to "Sdk Assemblies Only". Having it set to this, i get following error.

[image: First Error]

I have tried setting linking to "None", like it is in debug mode, but that just causes a seperate list of error, which is even more confusing.

[image: Secound set of Errors.]

The errors in the image above, are in total 11 errors in Visual Studio.
These errors arouse after i had to increase the targeted Android version from 9 to 10, to support Googles Api requirement for new apps on Google Play. The updateing of Xamarin Form from version 4.4.0.936621-pre1 to 4.8.0.1560, might also have had an effect. Prior to changeing the targeted android version, it did however build just fine in debug mode, even with the higher Xamarin Forms version.

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 version 16.7.6, at the moment, if that is any help.
I have also implemented option A of the Workaround in the following link, to avoid the bug that the link talks about. This is another thing i thourght were good to mention, incase it has any effects on the result. [Bug Workaround](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1120933/xabld7019-systemunauthorizedaccessexception-access.html)

Take note that the secound set of errors mentions a file called "proguard.cfg". That file does exist at the mentioned location. What is confounding is why it is mentioning that file, as i have not set Code Shrinker on the android project to anything, ie it is blank.

It is not a necessity to solve both sets of errors. That said, solving the first one, might simply mean that is also shows the secound set of error in the scenario where it is currently showing the first error. Because of this, it would be ideal to solve both errors, but at minimum the secound one.

Feel free to ask for more information. I can howerver not supply a packaged solution, with the errors, as it is for a company project, where i am not allowed to disclose the code. I tried to include the errors as text, but StackOverflow, sees it as code and therefore expects a specific formationg. Feel free to ask for it in text, if you need it, and i will try to supply it.

Comment: Does th error occure when you create the new project? If not, what do you do before the error thrown?

Comment: The errors occur when i attempt to build an existing Xamarin Android project. I don't know if a new project will throw the errors - I will check a little later.

Comment: On a fresh Visual Studio 19 install, on my personal PC,I only had the first error when attempting to build the project in the question. Building in debug mode, worked just fine. This indicates to me that the second set of errors are PC specific.

On a completely new Xamarin Forms and Xamarin Android project, targeting the same versions as in the question, it builds without errors in both debug and release mode. Plz for the love of god, do not force me to copy EVERYTHING from the old to the new, slowly, to fix the error...

Comment: I guess the error caused when you do the migration. The quick way is to copy from old to the new.

Comment: I created a new solution, and copied over the code. From there i re-added the references to nuget packages and the company libraries (Core, Xamarin and Droid). From this point, it builds just fine in Debug mode, ie with Linking set to "None", but still throws the first error in Release mode, ie when Linking is set to "Sdk Assemblies Only". This means it fixed the second set of errors, but not the first. Atleast now i should be able to create an APK to upload to google play, albeit a larger fine. Would still love a fix to the first one in the future.

Comment: As it is only the second set of errors that has been solved, i wouldn't exactly called this issue solved. if it had been the other way around then yes, i would have added it as a answer and marked it as accepted. It is not ideal to be unable to use the Linking, as it results in larger APK's.